# Lorenz equations with negative parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, chaos-theory

Consider the Lorenz system
$$\dot{x}(t) = \sigma(y-x) \, ,$$
$$\dot{y}(t) = x(\rho-z) - y \, ,$$
$$\dot{z}(t) = xy-\beta z \, .$$
Usually one considers the parameters $\sigma, \rho,$ and $\beta$ to be positive. Is there an inherent problem in the system if these parameters are negative?

Comment: The parameters represent physical quantities which are positive by definition.

Comment: Hi @Hikaru, sure, that's true- but mathematically what happens to the ODE's solutions?